# Asyncpg set_type_coding not working on FastAPI using an AsyncSession

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, asyncpg

I am using FastAPI with asyncpg and sqlalchemy. The FastAPI app uses "long-lived" sqlalchemy sessions to facilitate the use of PostGres prepared statements, which speeds up request times.
Note that prepared statements only last for the duration of the current database session, cf. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html.

Using this setup, querying the database returns `decimal.Decimal` as dtype for certain columns, I require `float`.

I tried to fix this using the approach documented here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html

Calls to the db still return columns in `decimal.Decimal` type, however.
What am I missing?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine

app = FastAPI()

db_engine = create_async_engine(f"postgresql+asyncpg://user:pw@localhost:5432/my_db")

db_session = None 

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    # Generate db session
    global db_session 
    db_session = AsyncSession(db_engine, autocommit=False, future=True)

    # Prepare SQL statements for speeding up request times using https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html
    db_session = await prepare_statements(...)

    # Register type codec
    @event.listens_for(db_session.bind.sync_engine, "connect")
    def register_custom_types(dbapi_connection):
        dbapi_connection.run_async(
            lambda connection: connection.set_type_codec(
                'numeric', encoder=str, decoder=float,
                 format='text', schema = "pg_catalog"
            )
        )
```

My setup includes:

- asyncpg 0.25.0
- sqlalchemy 1.4.17
- fastapi 0.65.1
- python 3.9.4
- Windows & Linux (works on neither)

Comment: Does the conversion codec work with pure asyncpg?  It would be helpful to establish whether the problem is in asyncpg or SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I switched to asyncpg directly, bypassing sqlalchemy, and now it works.